# python Guess The Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

This is my take on the guess the number game. The user has three attempts to guess the number chosen at random. The number is between 0 and 9, including. It tells the user to guess higher or lower and reveals the number if the game is lost.

Input that is not a number between 0 and 9, including, is not accepted and the cursor will remain on the same line.

Green is for win and red is for retry.

I have tested the code and it works correctly. Please have a go.

`guess_the_number.py`

```
"""The user has three attempts to guess what number was chosen at random"""

__all__ = []

import random
import string

from colorama import deinit, init

right_answer = random.choice(string.digits)

as_int = int(right_answer)

MSG_ANS = 'The answer was ' + right_answer
MSG_ASK = 'Guess the number (0-9) '
MSG_OK = '\033[92mCorrect!\033[0m'
MSG_TRY = '\033[91mTry again *\033[0m'


def ask(msg_wrong):
    """
    One attempt

    Non-digits are not accepted

    Digits accepted are removed from the pool
    and are not accepted in subsequent attempts
    """
    global pool

    cursor_up = '\033[A'

    cursor_up_ask = cursor_up + '                       '

    while True:
        answer = input(MSG_ASK)

        if answer and answer in pool:
            break

        answer_sz = len(answer)
        answer_sz = answer_sz * ' '

        line = cursor_up_ask + answer_sz + cursor_up

        print(line)

        print()
        print()

        print(line, end='\r')

    if answer == right_answer:
        print(MSG_OK)

        exit()

    if msg_wrong == MSG_TRY:
        i = int(answer)

        if i > as_int:
            hint = '>'
        else:
            hint = '<'

        msg_wrong = msg_wrong.replace('*', hint)

    print(msg_wrong)

    pool = pool.replace(answer, '')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = string.digits

    init()

    ask(MSG_TRY)

    ask(MSG_TRY)

    ask(MSG_ANS)

    deinit()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Positives**

- Your function docstring was informative and helped me understand the code better.
- Good use of variables like `cursor_up` to manage the ANSI control characters

**Small improvements**

- As long as you're bringin in colorama, can you use any of the named constants in provides instead of the control characters?
- If you need to do something multiple times, I like to see if there's a good way to do `n` times instead. See if you can make the number of turns more configurable.
- I'm not sure what you're doing with `line = cursor_up_ask + answer_sz + cursor_up`. This would be a good place for a comment or a function with a clear name.
- You're taking `len(answer)`, but shouldn't that always be 1? My understanding is that you're expecting a one-digit answer. It would be nice to have some error handling so that, e.g. `23` isn't treated as a valid guess.
- You could eliminate the `pool` global by wrapping it and your functions together in a class. You could also eliminate the global by having more focused functions.
- Instead of doing a find-replace on the `*` in `MSG_TRY`, you can do something like this:

```
MSG_TRY = '\033[91mTry again {}\033[0m'
msg_wrong = msg_wrong.format(hint)
```

**Larger gripes**

- I'm finding the flow of the program hard to follow. Consider breaking it down into smaller functions so it's more clear what's going on. It could look something like:

```
def play_one_turn(final_turn = False):
    guess = get_player_input()
    if guess == right_answer:
        print(OK_MSG)
        return True
    if not final_turn:
        show_hint(guess)
    else:
        print(MSG_ANS)
```

(I'm not saying this is the best way to do things. It's showing how smaller well-named functions can give more clarity with the same structure)

- `exit()` in the middle of a function is suspicious. (Is the code missing `from sys import exit`?) I'd expect to see it at the end of a main function to return a status code back to the user. It should not be used for control flow. It would make more sense to return `True` or `False` depending on whether the guess is correct, and let the caller manage things from there.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does work, nice try :)

It's an interesting exercise. If you are open to another way of approaching the game, here's what I'd suggest:

```py
import random
import string

def possible_answers() -> list:
    #['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    return [char for char in string.digits]

def generate_answer() -> str:
    return random.choice(possible_answers())

def ask_for_input() -> str:
    print('Your guess > ', end='')
    return input()

def new_game(max_attempts: int):
    correct_answer = generate_answer()
    attempts = []
    print('Welcome to the new round :) ')
    while len(attempts) < max_attempts:
        attempt = ask_for_input()
        if attempt == correct_answer:
            print('Bingo')
            break
        elif attempt not in possible_answers():
            print(f'Invalid input, possible answers: {possible_answers()}')
        elif attempt in attempts:
            print('You already guessed that one, my friend. Try something new :)')
        else:
            attempts += [attempt]
            print('Please try again, best of luck with the next attempt :)')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        new_game(max_attempts = 3)
```

- We are creating a new game after the previous game ends.
- In Each game we:

  - accept a `max_attempts` as the game configuration
  - generate a random correct answer
  - accept attempts and act on the attempts accordingly
- You can easily change the random set by changing the `possible_answers()` method
- I'm ignoring output formatting here, but it can be easily added in the `new_game()` method.

If you don't mind doing a bit of reading, [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is something that's worth exploring. Hope you enjoy the reading and keep up the good work :)

Comment: Am really considering downvoting this answer.  You are providing an alternative code but without a reason why the said code is better than OP's code.